# RewriteCond: bad argument line '$1'

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel, whm

I wrote this code for my `.htaccess` before i use codeigniter framework.

```
#============
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Prevent index dirs
RewriteCond $1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# General dirs / files
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# Protect Folder Not Index
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(zip|rar)$">
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

when I wrote this code my website gave me an error **500 internal server error**

when i checked my apache error log it gave this error message:

> /home/.../public_html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '$1'

any solve for this ?

I have tried to comment on the line

```
# RewriteCond $1
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, working.. but the effect is that the sub domain in sub directory cannot be accessed (permission failed), and previously I deployed this application to hosting, and used cpanel, but it still failed.

Comment: On the line RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt), show should delete $1, as this RewriteCond !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)

Comment: @jacouh Deleting `$1` on that like makes no sense at all. (The first argument is not a regex.) That line looks perfectly OK as written. The line with an error is `# RewriteCond $1` - but that line is already commented out?

Comment: "I have tried to comment on the line" - Which line specifically are you referring to?

Comment: "but the effect is that the **sub domain in that directory** cannot be accessed (permission failed)" - Do you mean "subdirectory", not "sub domain". What request are you making and what response are you expecting?

Comment: yes, i mean the effect sub domain in sub directory, 403 forbidden cant access

Comment: You should fix the order in which you are doing things. Your external HTTP to HTTPS redirect, that should come first - before you start with any of your internal rewrites. And what point `RewriteCond $1` was supposed to have, I can't tell here.